# RabbitMQ stops publishing messages

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, eventmachine

I'm writing a script to send configurable push notifications to our the users of our app. I'm using the **amqp** gem. I set up a test exchange (direct) and a single queue bound to it. When I start the script I see the first few messages are published but none after that. I'm not sure what I have done wrong, but I assume it has something to do with the way I'm using the EventMachine api.

Here is the Rabbit module/function that publishes a JSON-formatted message. It was pretty much copy/pasted from various tutorials/websites:
module Rabbit

```
# functions needed to communicate with RabbitMQ server
    def publish_message_to_direct(server_params, exchange, messages)
        begin
            AMQP.start(server_params) do |connection|
                channel  = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)
                exchange = channel.direct(exchange,:durable=>true) 
                messages.each do
                    |msg|
                    exchange.publish(msg) do
                        puts "just published"   
                        connection.close do
                            puts "connection was closed!"
                            #EM.stop
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        rescue Exception => e
            puts "#{e.message} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
        end
        nil
    end
end
```

Here is the EM code that calls the publish function:

```
userids = Array.new
userids.push(1,2,3,12,23,34,56) # this could be any array of integers
EventMachine.run do
  exchangeName = 'test.push'
  EM.add_periodic_timer(1.0*delay/1000) do
    userid = $userids.pop
    data = Push.get_push_tokens_for_userid(userid) # we have to query db for tokens
    user_notifications = nil
    user_notifications = Array.new
    data.each_hash do 
      |row|
      begin
        notification = Rabbit.create_push_notification_json(
          "This is a push notification!",
          row['userid'].to_i, 
          row['token'], 
          Push.get_device_push_type(row['applicationid'].to_i)
          )   
        user_notifications.push(notification)
        pushEvents += 1
      rescue Exception => e 
        puts "#{e.message} #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
      end
    end
    if $userids.empty?
      EM.stop_event_loop
    else
      puts "about to publish"
      Rabbit.publish_message_to_direct(rmq_params,exchangeName,user_notifications)
      userids_pushed.push(userid)
    end
  end

  EM.add_timer(time) do
      EM.stop_event_loop
  end

  Signal.trap("INT") do
    EM.stop_event_loop
  end
end
```

The output looks like this, where a few messages get published in the beginning but then at some point they just stop:

```
just published
just published
just published
just published
just published
just published
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
about to publish
just published
connection was closed!
about to publish
just published
just published
just published
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
connection was closed!
about to publish
just published
connection was closed!
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
about to publish
   .
    .
    .
    about to publish
```

Honestly I have no idea what is going on at this point. It seems the connection is closing several times and then I assume doesn't get re-established at some point. What would cause this behavior and how can I fix it? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't know if it's causing your problems or not, but you close the connection inside your loop to handle each message.  That smells wrong to me.

Comment: @SomeGuy I agree. I'm thinking I need to just wrap AMQP around everything and have a single connection. It would be nice, however, to technically learn what is the specific cause of the problem.

Comment: I sometimes find that when I fix what looks wrong and the main problem goes away, it suddenly becomes obvious why it was causing it.  Also, for rabbitmq w/ ruby, I've had better luck with the bunny gem than anything else.  Might be worth a shot if you don't have a ton of code already written.